# How to start some function elsewhere but not in file function.php Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a small plugin.

I'm deleting a payment method if there is a chechout of some categories of goods.

I have some function, and filter:

```
    function filter_gateways($gateways){
    $payment_NAME = 'paypal'; // <-- some payment method
    $category_ID_1 = '6'; // <-- some category of products
    global $woocommerce;
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        // Get the terms, i.e. category list using the ID of the product
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        // List of the products category for a match
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            // $category_ID_1 is the ID of the category for which i want to remove the payment gateway
            if($term->term_id == $category_ID_1){
                unset($gateways[$payment_NAME]);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $gateways;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','filter_gateways');
```

This filter works in the file functions.php on the folder theme.

But if I use it in my plugin files - filter doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?How to make it work?

For, I pass my some variables in this filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is one of timing. Likely your plugin is loading before Woocommerce has had a chance to set up that filter so it just fails to do anything. Try wrapping the filter call inside an action to delay it's activation. I think `after_setup_theme` would be a good choice, but you may need to use a different one. You can see all of the default available actions here https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'do_filter_gateways' );

function do_filter_gateways()
{
    add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','filter_gateways');
}
```